# Set aws access key and secret key with secretsmanager Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the below terraform template which creates a user, access key and stores in secret manager.

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "test" {
  name = "test"
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "test" {
  user = aws_iam_user.test.name
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "test" {
  name = "credentials"
  description = "My credentials"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "test" {
  secret_id     = "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.test.id}"
  secret_string = "{\"AccessKey\": data.aws_iam_access_key.test.id,\"SecretAccessKey\": data.aws_iam_access_key.test.secret}"
}
```

The values in the secret_string is not getting set. Is this right usage? Please help me set the right values

```
secret_string = "{\"AccessKey\": data.aws_iam_access_key.test.id,\"SecretAccessKey\": data.aws_iam_access_key.test.secret}"
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass JSON with Terraform exported attributes as the argument value for `secret_string`?

Comment: yes you are right. I have the `id` and `secret` created as part of `aws_iam_access_key` resource. I need to pass this to the `secret_string` as JSON

Comment: Try `secret_string = jsonencode({"AccessKey" = data.aws_iam_access_key.test.id, "SecretAccessKey" = data.aws_iam_access_key.test.secret})"`.

Comment: I am getting this error `Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on iam.tf line 16, in resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "test":
  16:   secret_string = jsonencode({"AccessKey" = data.aws_iam_access_key.test.id, "SecretAccessKey" = data.aws_iam_access_key.test.secret})

A data resource "aws_iam_access_key" "test" has not been declared in the root
module.
`

Comment: it works without data  `secret_string = jsonencode({"AccessKey" = aws_iam_access_key.test.id, "SecretAccessKey" = aws_iam_access_key.test.secret})
`

Comment: Right, that makes sense because those are resources and not data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can construct your `secret_string` argument value as a Map type, and then encode it into a JSON string using Terraform's native `jsonencode` function to ensure the value is passed correctly to the argument. Your resource would look like:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "test" {
  secret_id     = "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.test.id}"
  secret_string = jsonencode({"AccessKey" = aws_iam_access_key.test.id, "SecretAccessKey" = aws_iam_access_key.test.secret})
}
```

Note also that `aws_iam_access_key.test.id` and `aws_iam_access_key.test.secret` are exported attributes from resources and not data, so the `data` prefix needs to be removed from their namespace.